# How to use a short name for a long domain name

Tags: macos, domain

I don't want add an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file but rather refer to the following domain: `git.domain.com` as `git` and type it as such when I want to connect to this server?

Is this possible without using the `hosts` file?

Comment: Please add some detail: you're saying you don't want a `hosts` solution, but you're not explaining why that would not work for you. That makes it hard to guess what a good solution would be. And what kind of connections are you making? Like: does the remote server need to know the full name (like: is it used for virtual web hosting)?

Comment: What protocols? For `git`? `ssh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is exactly what "Search Domains" are for in DNS.

In `System Preferences > Networking > [Interface] > Advanced… > DNS > Search Domains…`, enter "domain.com" in the list.

Then you can just type `git` and OS X's DNS resolver library will automatically try appending `.domain.com` to it, resulting in a lookup for `git.domain.com`. If your DNS server is able to find an IP address for `git.domain.com`, you'll be able to connect.